# Health check proxied DNS

Tags: dns, ping, http, nmap, cloudflare

I am attempting to send a ping health check to a proxied Cloudflare DNS record, as expected my ping is just resolving to Cloudflare DNS. This gives me inaccuracies since the server behind the Cloudflare DNS could be down yet still receive a health 200OK response from the ping since Cloudflares DNS is up.

Is there any possible way besides using Cloudflares Health Check API endpoint, to get an accurate ping response from the server, to verify correct DNS configuration.